# Is it possible to containerize a cluster?

Tags: containers, minikube, minishift

Is it possible to containerize a minishift or minikube cluster? So that I can `docker run -it` the container, and `oc/kubectl get` the resources inside?

The Dockerfile could be like:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN **minishift installation**
ENTRYPOINT ['minishift', 'start']
```

We currently have a product that has a minishift cluster in a VM, so I was wondering if we can transition it from VM to Container.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes this might be possible. But this should not be done this way.

While I do understand running [Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) or [Minishift](https://github.com/minishift/minishift) inside a Virtual Machine, I cannot understand why you would like to run in inside a container. Both of those are just one node easy to use Kubernetes or OpenShift.

If you already have a cluster why not used it to run the app that you want.
By deploying Minikube or MiniShift into a container, you are creating a huge overhead for your application.

You might be interested in reading this blog [Running systemd within a Docker Container](https://rhatdan.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/running-systemd-within-a-docker-container/). It is a bit dated but it might be something that you are looking for. [Daniel Walsh](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/author/rhatdan/) also posted an update in 2019 for that post from 2014, you can find it [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/24/how-to-run-systemd-in-a-container/)